# Can't deploying a github private repository that itself references a private github repository Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, kudu, azure-web-app-service

`"name": "***",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.10.2",
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "efu-core": "git+https://longToken:x-oauth-basic@github.com:OrgName/RepositoryName.git",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.3",
    "path-to-regexp": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "slick-carousel": "1.5.9",
    "validator": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.6.5",`

And got result at logs during deployment:

`Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Start script "./bin/www" from package.json is not found.
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
Using start-up script app.js
Generated web.config.
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 4.2.3.
Selected npm version 3.5.1
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit 
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+ssh://git@github.com/OrgName/RepositoryName.git resetting remote D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-EyeFitU-RepositoryName-acc961db0e2e13aa3399e1b1d90f4333 because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/EyeFitU/EyeFitU.Client.Core.git D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-...`

How I can reference at azure to private github repository?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is not about deploying a private repository, but about deploying a repository that itself *references* a private repository. Probably should rephrase title to clarify.

Comment: You might want to read through http://blogs.suwatbodin.com/2013/07/deploy-to-windows-azure-using-git-with.html which discusses related things.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?